# How to Delete Blob from Azure Storage using BlobClient

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to delete several blobs blobs from Azure storage using the `BlobClient` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet).

```
private static void DeleteBlobsFromContainer(Uri blobUri, List<string> fileNames)
{
    foreach (var fileName in fileNames)
    {
        var uri = new Uri(blobUri, fileName);
        BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(uri);
        //blobClient.Delete(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
        blobClient.DeleteIfExists(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
    }
}
```

Here is what it looks like in the debugger:

[image: My blobUri looks like]

I can download/stream the blobs just fine using the same `BlobClient` class. I don't understand why the delete related methods for the `BlobClient` aren't working.

I am getting this message: "Azure.RequestFailedException: 'The specified resource does not exist."

Below is a picture from my Azure storage showing some of the blobs in the container.

[image]

Note: I just started programming a few months back. Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you authorizing your requests to delete the blobs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should specify a SAS token to the uri of blob.

Code like below:

```
var sasToken="your sastoken";
var uri = new Uri(blobUri, fileName+sastoken);

BlobClient blobClient = new BlobClient(uri); 
blobClient.DeleteIfExists(DeleteSnapshotsOption.IncludeSnapshots);
```

FYI: This is how to generate a sasToken via azure portal:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for checking out my other post as well. This is where I was headed with that other post, which I just deleted. You are amazing, thank you SO MUCH. I spent 7 hours on this yesterday and couldnt find any documentation. Was there an article you found to do this or did you know from experience? Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I find it a little strange that I'm able to stream the data from the blobs without that SAS key considering the "read" allowed permission.

Comment: @JustinFeistner, usually, we follow this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet) to operate with blob(it uses `BlobServiceClient` and `connectionString` to authenticate with azure storage, then operate with `blob container`, then operate with `blob file`). And in your case, if you want to directly access a blob file without using `BlobServiceClient` and `connectionString` to authenticate, then you need to add a sasToken to the blob uri, there is no doc about this. We guessed and tested it out previously.